# Android: почему можно вызвать startActivityForResult() в AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, ui, android-asynctask

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста, почему андроид позволяет выполнять этот код:

```
private class SignInTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {
   @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    try {
       ...
    } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException recoverableException) {
        Intent recoveryIntent = recoverableException.getIntent();
        startActivityForResult(recoveryIntent, REQUEST_AUTH);
    }
}
```

хотя везде говорится что из `doInBackground UI` недоступен?

Comment: Скорее всего внутри реализации startActivityForResult есть проверка и запуск активити в нужном потоке. Но лучше запускать черед runOnUiThread

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если заглянуть во внутренности `startActivityForResult()`:

```
2659    public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) {
2660        if (mParent == null) {
2661            Instrumentation.ActivityResult ar =
2662                mInstrumentation.execStartActivity(
2663                    this, mMainThread.getApplicationThread(), mToken, this,
2664                    intent, requestCode);
2665            if (ar != null) {
2666                mMainThread.sendActivityResult(
2667                    mToken, mEmbeddedID, requestCode, ar.getResultCode(),
2668                    ar.getResultData());
2669            }
2670            if (requestCode >= 0) {
2671                // If this start is requesting a result, we can avoid making
2672                // the activity visible until the result is received.  Setting
2673                // this code during onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) or onResume() will keep the
2674                // activity hidden during this time, to avoid flickering.
2675                // This can only be done when a result is requested because
2676                // that guarantees we will get information back when the
2677                // activity is finished, no matter what happens to it.
2678                mStartedActivity = true;
2679            }
2680        } else {
2681            mParent.startActivityFromChild(this, intent, requestCode);
2682        }
2683    }
```

И посмотреть далее, по цепочке вызовов (`Instrumentation.execStartActivity()` и т.д.), то становится очевидно, что вызов `startActivityForResult()` всегда передаёт `ActivityManager` (а точнее, обёртке над ним — `ActivityManagerNative`) контекст потока, создавшего текущую `Activity`, то бишь UI-thread, а стало быть, и запускаемая новая `Activity` всегда будет запущена в UI-thread, поскольку именно передаваемый контекст потока используется менеджером для биндинга сообщений и прочей магии.

И да, вы правы, работать с UI крайне желательно из UI-thread. Но операция запуска `Activity` работой с UI не является — это лишь команда `ActivityManager`'у создать новый компонент и забиндить на него очередь сообщений. А общаться с сервисами вы можете в любом потоке.

Comment: Супер ответ